# Cross-compiling Linux kernel using crosstool-ng based toolchain

Tags: linux-kernel, cross-compiling, beagleboneblack, armv7

I built a custom toolchain using crosstool-ng project for the BeagleBone Black SBC. I followed the instructions in the book "Mastering Embedded Linux Programming" which simply using the `arm-cortex_a8-linux-gnueabi` configuration. Building the toolchain works fine but when using it to cross-compile the Linux kernel (Using the `multi_v7_defconfig` from kernel version 4.19.70) I get a whole bunch of the following error:

`/tmp/ccMrtEje.s:43: Error: selected processor does not support 'dmb ish' in ARM mode`

Where `dmb ish` can be any unsupported instruction found by the toolchain assembler. I tried the official kernel fork for the BeagleBone [here](https://github.com/beagleboard/linux) which has `bb.org_defconfig`, so I used it and I get the same error. Seems it is a toolchain problem. Could I be missing something while configuring the toolchain? I already set the FPU to be hardware, still not familiar with a lot of configuration options.

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly suggest to use a GCC toolchain from [Linaro](https://www.linaro.org/downloads/) or [ARM](https://developer.arm.com/tools-and-software/open-source-software/developer-tools/gnu-toolchain/gnu-a).
I was able to build a 4.19.70 kernel for your target configuration with gcc-arm-8.3-2019.03-x86_64-arm-eabi without problems using the following commands:

```
wget "https://developer.arm.com/-/media/Files/downloads/gnu-a/8.3-2019.03/binrel/gcc-arm-8.3-2019.03-x86_64-arm-eabi.tar.xz?revision=402e6a13-cb73-48dc-8218-ad75d6be0e01&la=en" -O gcc-arm-8.3-2019.03-x86_64-arm-eabi.tar.xz
tar Jxf gcc-arm-8.3-2019.03-x86_64-arm-eabi.tar.xz

wget https://cdn.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v4.x/linux-4.19.70.tar.xz
tar Jxf linux-4.19.70.tar.xz

CROSS_COMPILE=$(pwd)/gcc-arm-8.3-2019.03-x86_64-arm-eabi/bin/arm-eabi- ARCH=arm make -C linux-4.19.70 mrproper multi_v7_defconfig bzImage

ls -gG linux-4.19.70/arch/arm/boot/zImage
-rwxrwxr-x 1 8655360 Sep 21 03:49 linux-4.19.70/arch/arm/boot/zImage
```

I hope this helps.